# how to get all keys and values in redis in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, key-value

I am creating a node API using javascript. I have used redis as my key value store.
I created a redis-client in my app and am able to get values for perticular key.

I want to retrieve all keys along with their values.
So Far I have done this :

```
app.get('/jobs', function (req, res) {
    var jobs = [];
    client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        if(keys){
            for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
                client.get(keys[i], function (error, value) {
                    if (err) return console.log(err);
                    var job = {};
                    job['jobId']=keys[i];
                    job['data']=value;
                    jobs.push(job);
                });  
            }
            console.log(jobs);
            res.json({data:jobs});
        }
    });
});
```

but I always get blank array in response.

is there any way to do this in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Cmon, @Bhushan -- with 3K points you'd know better than to make a question without any code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis command to get all available keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252099/redis-command-to-get-all-available-keys)

Comment: @MoshMage I added the code. sorry as I was kinda busy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38247686/3784008

Comment: @BhushanGadekar You can check my answer below.

Comment: This question is about returning values from async functions, so it's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, the issue in your question is that, inside the `for` loop, `client.get` is invoked with an *asynchronous* callback where the *synchronous* `for` loop will not wait for the asynchronous callback and hence the next line `res.json({data:jobs});` is getting called immediately after the `for` loop before the asynchronous callbacks. At the time of the line `res.json({data:jobs});` is getting invoked, the array `jobs` is still empty `[]` and getting returned with the response.

To mitigate this, you should use any promise modules like `async`, `bluebird`, `ES6 Promise` etc.

Modified code using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module,

```
app.get('/jobs', function (req, res) {
    var jobs = [];
    client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        if(keys){
            async.map(keys, function(key, cb) {
               client.get(key, function (error, value) {
                    if (error) return cb(error);
                    var job = {};
                    job['jobId']=key;
                    job['data']=value;
                    cb(null, job);
                }); 
            }, function (error, results) {
               if (error) return console.log(error);
               console.log(results);
               res.json({data:results});
            });
        }
    });
});
```

> But from the `Redis` [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys), it is observed that usage of
>   Keys are intended for debugging and special operations, such as
>   changing your keyspace layout and not advisable to production
>   environments.

Hence, I would suggest using another module called [redisscan](https://github.com/fritzy/node-redisscan) as below which uses `SCAN` instead of `KEYS` as suggested in the `Redis` [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys).

Something like,

```
var redisScan = require('redisscan');
var redis     = require('redis').createClient();


redisScan({
        redis: redis,
        each_callback: function (type, key, subkey, value, cb) {
            console.log(type, key, subkey, value);
            cb();
        },
        done_callback: function (err) {
            console.log("-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-");
            redis.quit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: this sounds good but not working my case as the key is of hash type client.get takes only string type

Answer (score 9):

Combination of 2 requests:

```
import * as ioredis from 'ioredis';

const redis = new ioredis({
    port: redisPort,
    host: redisServer,
    password: '',
    db: 0
  });

const keys = await redis.collection.keys('*');
const values = await redis.collection.mget(keys);
```

Order will be the same for both arrays.

Comment: this is not working. there is no keys property

Comment: what i really wanted to know is how to limit keys

Comment: @rakesht - looks like it is there https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/828#issuecomment-476716136

Comment: if you want to limit then use scan method to get keys, its fast and reliable and non blocking..

Answer (score 5):

This will get all keys but with no values:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

client.keys('*', (err, keys) => {
  // ...
});
```

Now you need to get the values for those keys in a usual way. For example:

```
Promise.all(keys.map(key => client.getAsync(key))).then(values => {
  // ...
});
```

or with `async` module or in any way you like.

Comment: Worth to mention that the documentation explicitly states that this command should not be used to do that

Comment: @baao Yeah. I would argue that getting all keys and all values is a need that demonstrates that Redis is used in a strange way here. Unfortunately the question is about a solution, not a bout a problem, so it's hard to recommend anything else.

Comment: _that Redis is used in a strange way here_ That's true.  :D

Comment: Despite the question, a better solution would be to use `SCAN` instead of `KEYS`.

Answer (score 4):

You should never do this. First off, it is not recommended to use `KEYS *` in production. Second, this does not scale (cluster).

You can organise your cached entries into SETs and query for the items within the SET, then retrieve the references keys. This also makes invalidation easier.

Have a look at some data storage best practices.

https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro
[how to get all keys and values in redis in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926990/how-to-get-all-keys-and-values-in-redis-in-javascript)