# Array.push doesn't work when trying to push an oject received from redis cache in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, node-redis

I'm having this issue where I want to get all of the keys in my redis' cache, store them in an array and send that array with express to the user. The problem is that I receive an empty array in the response with no objects in it. I have tried using `for (const x of ...) {...}` but that didn't work either. Tried searching up for answers on the internet , still nothing. Can you explain why is this happening and also here's my code.

```js
exports.fetch = (_req, res) => {
  redis.keys("*", (err, reply) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
    else {
      const rooms = [];
      reply.map((key) => {
        redis.get(key, (err, room) => {
          if (err) console.error(err);
          else rooms.push(room);
        });
      });

      return res.json(rooms);
    }
  });
};
```

### **Update**

Thanks everyone for responding.

As @boolfalse suggested, I used `async` module and it worked!

Here's my updated code

```js
exports.fetch = (_req, res) => {
  redis.keys("*", (err, reply) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
    else {
      async.map(
        reply,
        (key, cb) => {
          redis.get(key, (err, room) => {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            else return cb(null, room);
          });
        },
        (err, results) => {
          if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
          else return res.json(results);
        }
      );
    }
  });
};
```

But I kinda don't understand why and how it worked...

Thanks anyways for doing research and providing your time

Comment: Are you actually getting anything back from redis in `reply`?

Comment: Yes. To be exact, when I `console.log(reply)` it sends a perfectly valid reply. I even tried feeding it with more data to see that by myself and indeed it logs each reply

Comment: There's no sense to write this again.. I believe the problem that you didn't used it asynchronously.. so folow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43059247/7574023)

Comment: Ok thanks @boolfalse. Will check it out now and let you know. (though I have seen the questions/answers in that thread)

Comment: will wait.. I'm interested too ;)

Comment: Your `return res.json(rooms)` runs before any callbacks from `redis.get()` run.

Comment: Check the updated question everyone, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you too @michael.grigoryan jan

Comment: I really wasn't expecting this 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user @boolfalse for helping me out.

[Here's the solution URL to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926990/how-to-get-all-keys-and-values-in-redis-in-javascript/43059247#43059247).

> First of all, the issue in your question is that, inside the `for` loop, `client.get` is invoked with an *asynchronous* callback where the *synchronous* `for` loop will not wait for the asynchronous callback and hence the next line `res.json({data:jobs});` is getting called immediately after the `for` loop before the asynchronous callbacks. At the time of the line `res.json({data:jobs});` is getting invoked, the array `jobs` is still empty `[]` and getting returned with the response.

> To mitigate this, you should use any promise modules like `async`, `bluebird`, `ES6 Promise` etc.

> Modified code using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module,

```js
    app.get('/jobs', function (req, res) {
        var jobs = [];
        client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            if(keys){
                async.map(keys, function(key, cb) {
                   client.get(key, function (error, value) {
                        if (error) return cb(error);
                        var job = {};
                        job['jobId']=key;
                        job['data']=value;
                        cb(null, job);
                    }); 
                }, function (error, results) {
                   if (error) return console.log(error);
                   console.log(results);
                   res.json({data:results});
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

> But from the `Redis` [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys), it is observed that usage of
> Keys are intended for debugging and special operations, such as
> changing your keyspace layout and not advisable to production
> environments.

> Hence, I would suggest using another module called [redisscan](https://github.com/fritzy/node-redisscan) as below which uses `SCAN` instead of `KEYS` as suggested in the `Redis` [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys).

> Something like,

```js
    var redisScan = require('redisscan');
    var redis     = require('redis').createClient();
           
    
    redisScan({
            redis: redis,
            each_callback: function (type, key, subkey, value, cb) {
                console.log(type, key, subkey, value);
                cb();
            },
            done_callback: function (err) {
                console.log("-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-");
                redis.quit();
            }
        });
```