# Node.js and Redis: How do I add items to a function wide object from within the callback?

Tags: node.js, redis

So, if I have something like the following:

```
 let searchObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
   var info = client.runFunction(variable, 0, -1, async function(err, result){
    var amount = parseInt(result[0]);
    searchObj[result1[i]] = amount;
  });
}
```

How can I access searchObj from outside of the callback? If I debug and print from within the callback, it works, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get all keys and values in redis in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926990/how-to-get-all-keys-and-values-in-redis-in-javascript#43059247)

Comment: That's super helpful, thank you. Will check it out.