# Get a keys matching pattern from Redis cache - node-redis

Tags: javascript, redis, node-redis

I am trying to cache a paginated API call. To fetch the data from Mongo DB using EXPRESS API.

Currently I am storing a page wise data in cache, with key structure mentioned below,

```
Key :1 
 {
   model: 'bookmarks',
   userId: '609bf4a1e9df4334acb2da7a',
   collection: '0',
   page: '1'
 }
Key 2
 {
   model: 'bookmarks',
   userId: '609bf4a1e9df4334acb2da7a',
   collection: '0',
   page: '2'
 }
```

and so on.

My use case is , if user has made an update to data fetched for particular collection example (0) , I intend to delete all the keys w.r.t. the collection present in the Redis client.

So far I have been able to get all the keys using 'keys *', I can filter and delete data from here, but as recommended in docs it's not recommended for production.

```
    redisClient.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('keys', keys);
      let newArray = [];
      console.log('keys', newArray);
      keys.forEach(function (key) {
        newArray.push(JSON.parse( key));
      });
      console.log('keys', newArray);
})
```

I am new to node-redis. Need help to understand the commands to get the key matching a pattern
{model:'bookmarks',collection:'0',userId:'1234:'}
so that I can clear cache for all the occurrences.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Redis SCAN in NODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642762/using-redis-scan-in-node)